# Does ServiceStack caching support AppFabric?

Tags: servicestack

I was wondering if ServiceStack caching api works with AppFabric or if someone has done something similar already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have an implementation out of the box, but you do have [an Azure Cache implementation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Contrib/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Caching.Azure), which has all that you might need to implement one yourself.

If you have already used DataCacheFactory, DataCache, etc. is not a big deal. ICacheClient has just a couple of short methods to implement.